# Workflow which should run automaticly, does not

Tags: designer-workflow, sharepoint-server

I am trying to implement a simple workflow (created in SPD 2010), which is supposed to fire an email to a user, as soon as a new list item is created.

The whole process looks like this:

1. The list recieves an email
2. The email is parsed
3. List item is created based on the contents of the email (logic by custom solution)
4. List item has property `Created by` of `system` (according to Google, this is likely causing the problem)
5. Workflow does not fire automaticly

Obviously the error is located in step 5. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Make sure the work flow isn't just running and erroring out.  Check the work flow history on an item to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to programmatically start a workflow on the new item (since you are already doing it with code)..

There are many examples available on internet, in short you need to get the [SPList.WorkflowAssociation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.workflowassociations.aspx) object and than call [SPSite.WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee559331%28v=office.14%29.aspx) method..

If you want to change the Initiator of the workflow, you can impersonate the SPSite object.. something like:

```
SPWeb oWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPUserToken token = oWeb.AllUsers[@"SHAREPOINTSYSTEM"].UserToken;

using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(oWeb.Site.ID, token))
{
    // your code
}
```

**Examples:**

[Starting workflow programmatically](http://blog.mmasood.com/2012/06/programatically-start-workflow.html)
[Howto Start a Sharepoint Workflow Programmatically](http://www.tonytestasworld.com/post/howto-start-a-sharepoint-workflow-programmatically.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a working solution, which did dumb down the problem itself. 
Instead of using a workflow (If you have a hammer, every problem looks like a nail), I went for a custom alert, which sends an email if a new item is added to the list in question.

This gives the client the functionality he wants and I did not need to use code.